# Тестирование проекта в Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Обновление моего приложения (назовем его Main) происходит через другую программу (назовем ее Update)
Алгоритм обновления такой

1. Приложение Main во время работы получает команду обновится и запускает Update
2. Update гасит все процессы Main и затем копирует вместо исполняемого файла Main новый файл с сервера обновлений
3. Update запускает уже обновленный Main, а сама завершает работу

Проблема в том, что на некоторых компьютерах приложение Update выдает ошибку. Но если мы запускаем ее в Visual studio ошибки не возникает. Видимо она возникает именно когда ее запускает приложение Main.

Отсюда у меня к сообществу следующий вопрос: как можно отладить программу в таком случае?

Или подскажите другой алгоритм обновлений.

Comment: Добавьте `Debugger.Break()`, тогда оно будет предлагать отладить себя на этой строчке.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей нужно использовать логирование, ведь сейчас вы гадаете на "кофейной гуще" и ищите ту или иную проблему. А проблем может быть множество, возьмем к примеру версии .NET; а может у пользователя попросту нет прав для изменения файлов. Вот для этого всего и надо узнавать конкретно что и где у вас "падает", а в этом помогает именно логирование.

Скажем процесс следующий:

- Вы создали приложение.
- В него вы добавили библиотеку NLog (или подобные ей, можно простенький свой логер написать, а можно использовать сайты по сбору логов (к примеру Exceptionless)).
- В коде проставили в нужных местах отлавливание того, что у вас происходит "под капотом". И также подписались на событие, которое происходит при необработанной ошибке.
- Все, со временем работы программы вы будете видеть в файле все его действия и если произойдет ошибка, то достаточно взять у пользователя лог и посмотреть его.

Comment: Проблема в том что у меня уже стоит логирование, но оно меня не спасает он просто пишет что адреса сервера обновления не существует. Уже перепробывала все варианты. Вот и хотела увидеть не только лог ошибки, но и то как вели себя переменные обновлялки. Или вы знаете как описать все переменные в логе? Что ж поделитесь

Comment: @polsok Лог - это запись куда либо ту или иную информацию. В любой лог можно засунуть что вашей душе угодно. К примеру в `NLog` логирование идет примерно так: `Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Ошибка: Адрес сервера {url} не существует", ex);` То есть видно, что я указал в логе его уровень, переменную нужную и объект `Exception`, который в лог файле развернется и отобразит ошибку и другую информацию. По поводу описать все переменные - это зависит от того, где у вас эти переменные. Один вариант - переписать `ToString()` и тогда можно в сообщение написать `MyClass.ToString()` и он выдаст все нужное.

Comment: @polsok [вот](https://pastebin.com/uPpBrDAm) к примеру я воспроизвел падение своего приложения, где я отлавливаю все ошибки в отдельный файл. В нем я четко вижу, что у меня произошла фатальная ошибка при вызове `Core.Settings.Load()` в файле `Settings.cs` на строке 88. Я вижу конкретно ошибку о невозможности загрузить `Newtonsoft.Json` и мне этого достаточно для того, что бы в дальнейшем исправить баг. А вот пример того, как у меня идет `Debug` [уровень](https://pastebin.com/V0kk1pgh), как видите, все переменные я логирую и это очень классно помогает!